# How do I overwrite method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overwrite

I have a bit of a dilemma where in `fileB` I need to call on class `classC` but before I do that I need to overwrite `functionA`. I'm not sure how to do this. thank you for any help in advance!

```
#fileA

class classA():
    def functionA():
        print('Hello World!')


class classB(classA):
    pass

class classC(classB):
    pass


#fileB

from fileA import classC
#overwrite functionA
classC()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. You can use the same syntax in `fileB` to override `classC` as you did in `fileA`. Is there some method you're dynamically defining in `fileB`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "proper" way to do what you want is to *override* the method, not to overwrite it. You do that by creating a subclass of the class and providing a new definition for one or more of its methods.

First of all though there is an error in the definition of `classA.functionA()` - you need to include the `self` argument:

```
class classA:
    def functionA(self):
        print('Hello World!')
```

With that corrected you then need to define a new subclass of `classC` in `fileB.py` that overrides `functionA()`:

```
from fileA import classC

class classD(classC):
    def functionA(self):
        print('classD.functionA(): Hello World!')

>>> c = classC()
>>> c.functionA()
Hello World!

>>> d = classD()
>>> d.functionA()
classD.functionA(): Hello World!
```

It's worth pointing out that classes `classB` and `classC` seem pointless given that (as shown) they make no changes to the base class `A`. So you could directly subclass `classA` instead.

This is the most basic object oriented design/programming so I suggest that you look at a tutorial or two.

As I said above, this is the proper way to do it. You can also replace/overwrite the method like this:

```
from fileA import classC

def my_function_A(self):
    print('my_function_A(): Hello World!')

>>> c = classC()
>>> c.functionA()
Hello World!

>>> classC.functionA = my_function_A    # overwrite the method
>>> classC().functionA()
my_function_A(): Hello World!
>>> c.functionA()
my_function_A(): Hello World!
```

But overriding is preferable to overwriting it. One problem is that if you overwrite the method any preexisting instances of `classC` will also be affected as shown in the last line of the code above.

Comment: A quick note for your concluding statement: you can also create an instance of classC, then overwrite just that instance's my_function_A. This will leave classC itself untouched.

Comment: @JoelHarmon: yes that's right, however, I was trying to demonstrate that monkey patching might have unintended side effects.

Comment: I agree that it can cause problems (and also provide advantages, like any other trade off). However, since you brought up monkeypatching in your answer, I think it's better to provide a more complete/accurate representation of it. As written, your last sentence only applies to one use of monkeypatching, and thus I find it misleading.

Comment: @JoelHarmon: OP's question relates to patching of classes, not instances - if indeed the OP actually is using the correct terminology and not simply confusing _overwrite_ with _override_. There are several other aspects to this; I have mentioned one, an exhaustive description of monkey patching is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the technique you're looking for is monkeypatching.

Functions in Python are first-class objects. As such, you can simply assign them to a class or object. That does mean you can have two objects which are instances of the same class, that call two different methods even though the same name was invoked. They don't even have to be defined with the same name or even any name at all; I'm looking at you, Lambda.